# for loop causing bad text segmentation in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, for-loop, text-segmentation

the input images are [a.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Pah.jpg) and [b.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDZAi.jpg)
these two image stored in for example comp folder.and want to write the segmented image in segment folder.but I think for looping problem segmentation repeated for so many times for each image.And I could't solve the problem.
here is my code

```
Resultado='C:\Users\Nurul\Desktop\picsegment';
srcFiles = dir('C:\Users\Nurul\Desktop\comp\*.jpg');  
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
filename = strcat('C:\Users\Nurul\Desktop\comp\',srcFiles(i).name);
a = imread(filename);
LLL=a;
s=regionprops(LLL); 

figure,imshow(LLL);    title('segmented Image');
  hold on
for J=1:numel(s)  
 rectangle('Position',s(J).BoundingBox,'edgecolor','g')
 end
 im1=LLL;
 baseFileName = sprintf('%d.jpg', i); % e.g. "1.png"
 fullFileName = fullfile(Resultado, baseFileName); 
  imwrite(im1, fullFileName);
  end
```

plz help
thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I need to segment properly  each image only once.but this code segment each image so many times.

Comment: What to you mean "segment so many times"? This code  is not even complete. `regionprops` needs 2 inputs.

Comment: but using this same code only for one image I get proper segmented image!

Comment: my code is full.Binarization or others part I put in another script.calling that script  i just segment these image in this script.

Comment: When I run your code with just 1 image (b.jpg) it gives me 255 green boxes. Is that what you dont like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving your data as `jpg`, big mistake!

Still, if you want to keep the data saved as `jpg`, remember that it will not be saved as a binary image, and that means you need to binarize it again! Otherwise, every little pixel noise will be detected as data by `regionprops`, thats why you get so many squares.

Just add

```
a = imread(filename);

a=im2bw(a,0.5); % Add this line. The fancy way would be im2bw(a,graythresh(a)), but 0.5 will do in your case

LLL=a;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much! but in the folder why the segmented images  are not saved.only the binary images are saved

Comment: @EifaTasnim Please do not change the question. If you have a new question, ask a new one. Also, if this solved your problem, please accept it as valid

Comment: sorry.I will edit the 1st question.plz can you answer my current question?